# Iterating over sub items in a JSON array in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I know there's many answers regarding how to iterate over JSON items in Angular 2, but I'm having a field day (no pun intended) over trying to figure this one out:

```
{
    "datesofinterest": [ 
     {
        "name": "Holidays",
        "year": "2017",
        "version": "3.0",
        "dataitems": [{
            "langauage": "english",
            "listvalues": [{
                    "id": "bac34a",
                    "name": "New Year's Day",
                    "value": "New Year's Day",
                    "startdatetime": "02/01/2017 00:00:00 AM",
                    "enddatetime": "02/01/2017 11:59:59 PM",
                    "description":"The first day of the year",
                    "type":"statutory"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cad54b",
                    "name": "Family Day",
                    "value": "Family Day",
                    "startdatetime": "20/02/2017 00:00:00 AM",
                    "enddatetime": "20/02/2017 11:59:59 PM",
                    "description":"Board Game Day with the family",
                    "type":"statutory"
                },
                {
                    "id": "eac453a",
                    "name": "Good Friday",
                    "value": "Good Friday",
                    "startdatetime": "14/04/2017 00:00:00 AM",
                    "enddatetime": "14/04/2017 11:59:59 PM",
                    "description":"Easter",
                    "type":"statutory"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "langauage": "french",
            "listvalues": [{
                    "id": "af73jaah",
                    "name": "Jour de l'An",
                    "value": "Jour de l'An",
                    "startdatetime": "02/01/2017 00:00:00 AM",
                    "enddatetime": "02/01/2017 11:59:59 PM",
                    "description":"The first day of the year",
                    "type":"statutory"
                },
                {
                    "id": "lksf8us877",
                    "name": "Journée familiale",
                    "value": "Journée familiale",
                    "startdatetime": "20/02/2017 00:00:00 AM",
                    "enddatetime": "20/02/2017 11:59:59 PM",
                    "description":"Board Game Day with the family",
                    "type":"statutory"
                },
                {
                    "id": "l98jhsd",
                    "name": "Vendredi saint",
                    "value": "Vendredi saint",
                    "startdatetime": "14/04/2017 00:00:00 AM",
                    "enddatetime": "14/04/2017 11:59:59 PM",
                    "description":"Easter",
                    "type":"statutory"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

How would I write the *ngFor for this? Do the ngFors need to be in the same div or as a sub element of the main ngFor?

The ngFors that I have are:

```
*ngFor="let datesofinterest of alldatesofinterests"
*ngFor="let dataitem of datesofinterest.dataitems"
*ngFor="let listvalue of daysofinterest.dataitems.listvalues"
```

Comment: datesofinterest is not an array?

Comment: what is `alldatesofinterests` as per your json?

Comment: datesofinterest is an array - thank you for pointing that out

Comment: alldatesofinterests - this part of the Angular 2 directive to loop through the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 1 *ngFor on a single element. Also in your second ngFor you can use the declared `dataitem` variable from the first ngFor. You can use `<ng-container>` elements if you don't want to pollute the generated html with too much divs as they will not be rendered.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let dataitem of datesofinterest.dataitems">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let listvalue of dataitem.listvalues">
    {{listvalue.name}}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```